# Mac OS LaTeX install not compiling bibliography

Tags: bibtex, mac, mactex

I have recently installed LaTeX on my Mac using the standard MacTeX package. I have 2 documents (my thesis and a paper I'm writing) and I have tried to compile both.

Neither will compile the references or the bibliography... I keep getting the same error

> Citation undefined,
>      Undefined references,

I have the following code

#### `testDoc.tex`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenx}     

\begin{document}

This is my first document with a bibliography generated by Bib\TeX. Now I cite an article by Duffie\cite{Duffie2001}.

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{foo}    

\end{document}
```

In the same folder I have a `foo.bib` file.

#### `foo.bib`

```
@BOOK{Duffie2001,
title = {{Dynamic Asset Pricing Theory}},
year = {2001},
author = {Duffie, Darrell},
edition = {3}
}
```

Please note that this is just a simple example. My thesis has 100 references and my paper has 48.

When I compile that simple document it gives me the error :

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation `Duffie2001' on page 1 undefined on input line 7.
No file testDoc.bbl.
```

However I have not referenced a file `testDoc.bib` but `foo.bib`

If I rename `foo.bib` to `testDoc.bib` I get that same error.

---

Things I have tried

- I have tried 3 different editors each has the same error, Texmaker is my favourite and is the one I'm trying to get working
- I have checked the settings to ensure that Texmaker is pointing at the `bibtex` program, it is (I think) `/usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/x86_64-darwin/bibtex %.aux`

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 9):

Seems like you din’t run `bibtex` but only `(pdf)latex`, right?

LaTeX cares for typsetting the bib but you need another program (`bibtex`) to preprocess your `.bib` to be used by `pdflatex`. That means that you’ll need the following steps to get a bibliography

1. Create you `tex` file and the `bib` file.
2. Add the bib to your document with `\bibliography`
3. Run `pdflatex mydoc.tex` to get a first version of your document knowing which entries of your bib are needed
4. Run `bibtex mydoc` to let `bibtex` do the preprocessing based on the `aux` file. That’ll generate `mydoc.bbl` including all information that `pdflatex` needs
5. Run `pdflatex mydoc.tex` again to get the new `bbl` file included in your document

For further information please consult any (good) book about LaTeX this is a basic topic and should be explained there.

---

Pleas note that `bibtex` is kind of outdated. The better way is to use `biber` in combination with the package `biblatex`, which provides a great tool to format your citations and bibliography.

Comment: yeah your right, however I get the same problem if I run latex on it. If I run bibtex on the bib file I get the error.... Process started

I couldn't open file name `article_2.bib.aux'

Process exited with error(s)

Comment: As the erros tell you it’s looking for an aux file. `bibtex` needs `mydoc.aux` not `mybib.bib`. Actually the information on which `bib` should be used is included in the `aux` file …